# Incorrect file output using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

Hello everyone I am just learning my first programming language and have just corrected one error in my code only to be left with another error. Thankfully this is the last problem I need to solve but I'm having a little trouble doing it myself.

The program is to read in a customer number and expenses associated with each customer number. It will then add a finance charge, output all expenses, total everything, and save each customers new balance to file along with their ID number in reverse order.

beginningbalance.dat looks like

```
111
200.00
300.00
50.00
222
300.00
200.00
100.00
```

and newbalances.dat SHOULD look like

```
222
402.00
111
251.00
```

except depending on where in put the "count--" in the file writing loop, I end up with

```
222
402.00
111
251.00
-858993460
-92559631349317830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00
```

I can't figure out what I should do to get rid of these extra values. Any suggestions?

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
  int count = 0;
  const int size = 100;
  double customer_beg_balance, customer_purchases, customer_payments, finance_charge_cost, finance_charge = .01;
  int customer_number[size];
  double new_balance[size];
  double total_beg_balances=0,total_finance_charges=0,total_purchases=0,total_payments=0,total_end_balances=0;


  ifstream beginning_balance;
  beginning_balance.open("beginningbalance.dat");

  while(beginning_balance>>customer_number[count])
    {
        beginning_balance >> customer_beg_balance;
        beginning_balance >> customer_purchases;
        beginning_balance >> customer_payments;

        finance_charge_cost = customer_beg_balance * finance_charge;

        new_balance[count] = customer_beg_balance + finance_charge_cost + customer_purchases - customer_payments; 
        total_beg_balances+=customer_beg_balance;
        total_finance_charges+=finance_charge_cost;
        total_purchases+=customer_purchases;
        total_payments+=customer_payments;
        total_end_balances+=new_balance[count];

        cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<setw(8)<<"Cust No  "<<"Beg. Bal.  "<<"Finance Charge  "<<"Purchases  "<<"Payments  "<<"Ending Bal.\n"
            <<customer_number[count]<<"        "<<customer_beg_balance<<"        "<<finance_charge_cost<<"       "<<customer_purchases<<"     "<<customer_payments<<"         "<<new_balance[count]<<endl;


        count++;                            
    }

  cout<<"\nTotals     "<<total_beg_balances<<"        "<<total_finance_charges<<"       "<<total_purchases<<"     "<<total_payments<<"         "<<total_end_balances<<endl;

  ofstream new_balance_file;
  new_balance_file.open("NewBalance.dat");

  while(count >= 0)
  {
    count--;
    new_balance_file <<customer_number[count]<<endl;
    new_balance_file<< fixed<<setprecision(2)<<new_balance[count]<<endl;

  }


  new_balance_file.close();


system("pause");
        return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I see telltale signs of undefined behavior due to a lack of initialization looking solely at the output.

Comment: moshbear: Really?  I saw running past one end of an array

Comment: I wish people would try to debug their codes before bothering others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is wrong

```
 while(count >= 0)
 {
    count--;
    new_balance_file <<customer_number[count]<<endl;
    new_balance_file<< fixed<<setprecision(2)<<new_balance[count]<<endl;

 }
```

Should be `count > 0` instead of `count >= 0`.

This way count will iterate through values `n, n-1, ... 1` and because you decrement it right at the beginning of the while statement, the values you'll be operating with within your loop will be `n-1, n-2.... 0`, exactly what you need.

By the way, if your course has already covered the `for` loop and you're allowed to use it, then it's more suitable, like this

```
for(int i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    use i instead of count here.
}
```

Hope this helps and good luck with your studies!